# Surface plot over a triangular definition area

Tags: plotting

How do I illustrate the surface $f(x,y)=xy(x-y)$ over the area enclosed by the lines $y_1=2x$, $y_2=1-4x$, and $y_3=4+x/2$? TIA.

Comment: `Plot3D` with options `RegionFunction`?

Comment: `reg = ImplicitRegion[2 x<=y && 1- 4 x<=y && 4 +x/2>=y, {x,y}];
Plot3D[x y (x-y), {x, y} \[Element] reg] `?

Comment: I don't know if it is proper etiquette, but I use a comment anyway to send a Thanks! to all for the solutions. There are some interesting versions here that I've never seen and which inspires me to look more into the various suggested techniques.

Answer (score 5):

```
Plot3D[x y (x - y),
  {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[2 x < y && 1 - 4 x < y && 4 + x/2 >= y, {x, y}] ]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
triangle = Polygon[Join @@ ({x, y} /. Solve[Thread[# == y], {x, y}] & /@ 
      Subsets[ {2 x, 1 - 4 x, 4 + x/2}, {2}] )];
Plot3D[x y (x - y), {x, y} \[Element] triangle ]
```

> same picture